# ionic Version 1 Push Notification cordova-ios 4.4.0

Tags: ios, push-notification, amazon-sns, ionic-v1, phonegap-plugin-push

I am trying to implement push notification in ionic version 1 using "AWS SNS" and "Firebase"(for registering my ios and android application) and "phonegap-plugin-push" in ios,by using this plugin i got the token ,but using that token in aws to create endpoint to send the notification to my ios device ,unable to receive the notification,Kindly suggest any thrid party cordova plugin below the version of cordova-ios@4.4.0.

Note:
1.development certificate for ios for push notification are everything submitted.

As soon as end point created using fcm token(which is generated in ios device) in aws sns,end point getting disabled after the first push notification sent.

Answer (score 0):

use onesignal plugin for push notifications.
Its simple to use and have great documentation

Comment: thanks,but i have implemented using amazon push notification in ionic